# How to solve TypeError iterator is not a function with prototypejs when jquery is is noconflict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have [designed a page](http://iusefaith.com/standard_noconflict.php) where jquery works alongside other libraries like Prototypejs therefore i have put jquery in noconflict mode. **However when I resize the window**, firebug gives me the following  notification

> TypeError: iterator is not a function[Learn More]  prototype.js:859:7
>     forEach self-hosted:265:9   each
>   http://iusefaith.com/js/prototype/prototype.js:859:7  compressEvent
>   http://iusefaith.com/design/design1/app/common/assets/js/cache/front-2017073101.min.js:6579:13
>     
>   http://iusefaith.com/design/design1/app/common/assets/js/cache/front-2017073101.min.js:6575:1

I think I have put jquery in noConflict mode the right way. Here is my javascript code in no conflict mode

```
<!-- include javascript --> 
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script  src="js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
</script>
...
<script src="js/prototype/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 ...
<script src="design/design1/app/common/assets/js/cache/jquery-plugin-2017073101.min.js"></script>         

<script src="design/design1/app/common/assets/js/cache/front-2017073101.min.js"></script>
```

I am new to this type of error so please **How to solve TypeError iterator is not a function with prototypejs when jquery is is noconflict mode ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a very specific problem/bug in the resize javascript you are using but - this fixes your js error

line 6579 of front.js in the compress method of windowResizeClass

change the contents of the method from

```
    for (var k in windowResizer.resizeHandlers) {
        windowResizer.resizeHandlers[k]()
    }
```

to

```
    windowResizer.resizeHandlers.each(function(item){
            item();
    });
```

Comment: Looks like a bug (that should be reported!) in modernizr indeed. One [does not use `for…in` enumerations on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)!